# I can't get the value I want from a combobox

Tags: javascript, php, combobox

I want to add a new value in a object from a combobox and while I'm doing it like I did with the other values I get a message that it's undefined. any ideas how to fix it?

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //the ip-address will have to change to the ip of the host of the app.
    //in my case the ip is 192.168.1.68
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080'); 
    var chatForm = $(".chatForm"),
        messageInputField = chatForm.find("#message"),
        messagesList = $("#container"), //taked the name container to match the name of the css and work with the jquery draggabilly
        usernameForm = $(".username-setter"),
        usernameInput = usernameForm.find(".username-input"),
        comboBox = $(".comboboxvalue"),
        category = comboBox.find("#indexNr");
```

index.php

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-8">
                <h2>WorkShoppy Messages Application</h2>
                <h3>Username:  <span class="username label label-primary" ></span></h3>
                <div class="row" id="set">
                    <form class="username-setter" action="index.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Set username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control username-input" >
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Set</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <label for="indexNr">Category</label>
                <br>
                <select id="indexNr" id="indexNr" name="indexNr">
                    <option value="positive" class="comboboxvalue">Positive</option>
                    <option value="negative" class="comboboxvalue">Negative</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You have 2 `id` attributes in this line `<select id="indexNr" id="indexNr" name="indexNr">`

Comment: well it solved nothing. I tried it also with only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace these lines

```
 comboBox = $(".comboboxvalue"),
    category = comboBox.find("#indexNr");
```

with

```
category =     $("#indexNr").val()
```

or

```
category = $("#indexNr option:selected").val();
```

also remove additional id attribute into select.

Comment: glad to help :) consider accepting answer if it works for you .. :)